# "str contains" Function SIDDHI

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

i have a queshion.

Can I make a query and use the "str:contains" function with two events.

For example replace:

```
 from DSBStream[(str:contains(correlation_phr_incident_detail, '0.0.0.0')==FALSE)]
select *
insert into DSBFiltered;
```

BY

```
from DSBStream#window.length(0) join Trazablack as t
on (str:contains(correlation_phr_incident_detail, t.atribute)==FALSE)
select t.sensorValue as sensorValue
insert current events into trazawhite;
```

this is possible?

Comment: Is Trazablack a stream?

Comment: Trazablack is a table.

Comment: @From(eventtable='rdbms', jdbc.url='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pruebabg', username='postgres', password='Easysoft16', driver.name='org.postgresql.Driver', table.name='Trazablack')
define table Trazablack (atribute string);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible since Trazablack is a RDBMS event table. As a work around you can divide the query in to two parts where first query will get atribute from table by joining and second query will check srt:contains.